# zabbix_server can't receive UnixODBC data

Tags: odbc, zabbix

ODBC worked well,but zabbix_server's odbc item can't receive data any more.

```
[root@SqlRun ~]# isql -v zabbix
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> quit;
```

and with odbc compiled:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/zabbix --enable-server --enable-agent --enable-proxy --enable-ipv6 --enable-java -with-mysql -with-libcurl -with-libxml2 -with-unixodbc -with-openipmi -with-openssl -with-ldap -with-net-snmp -with-ssh2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqpuY.png)
have someone met this? thx in advance.

Comment: Please specify what is "any more" (did it work before? what changed?), which Zabbix version you are using and how exactly it fails. Wild guess - maybe this bug ? https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-11584

Comment: ty @Richlv  i'd just mis-spell the dsn: '<>' shoud be non-include,my dsn is 'zabbix',not  '<zabbix>'.

Comment: Sorry, that does not seem to answer any of my questions.